# Implicit function question: Given that $u=f\big(x,y,g(x,y)\big)$, express $∂^2u/∂y^2$ and $∂^2u/∂x∂y$ using partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem

this is my first time using StackExchange so I don't really know if anybody would help me out but here I go!
The question I had while solving practice questions for the [Implicit Function Theorem] is as follows. (The question's actually kinda short - same as the title)

"Given that $u=f(x,y,g(x,y))$, express $∂^2u/∂y^2$ and $∂^2u/∂x∂y$ using partial derivatives of f and g."

If anybody could help me out, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks x

Comment: Use the Chain Rule.

Comment: To help you get started, using the chain rule as Tito suggested above \begin{align} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \\ \implies \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}  &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) \\ &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right) \\ &= \dots \end{align} etc.

Comment: Thanks so much! The comments were very helpful :)